Playwright open VSCode then throws Error: Process failed to launch
When I execute the following test with npx playwright test it opens VSCode as expected but then fails instantly with the following message: Error: Process failed to launch!
What could be the problem here?
vscode.test.ts
    import { test } from "@playwright/test";
    import {_electron as electron} from "playwright-core";
    
    test.describe("VSCode Extension Installation from VSIX", async () => {
    
      test("VSCode launches and has correct window title", async () => {
        const vscodeApp = await electron.launch({
          executablePath: "/usr/bin/code",
        });
        const page =  await vscodeApp.firstWindow();
      });
    });

playwright.config.ts
    import { defineConfig } from "@playwright/test";
    import dotenv from "dotenv";
    
    import path from "path";
    dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, ".env") });


    export default defineConfig({
      testDir: "./e2e/tests",
        trace: "on-first-retry",
      },
      projects: [
        {
          name: "VSCode",
          use: {
            headless: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

I tried downloading and using a different instance of VSCode but got the same result.
